# Ran out of trampolines of type 0

Tags: iphone, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm writing an app for the Iphone using Monotouch. When I deploy the application on my iphone I get the error at runtime Thu Mar 10 23:38:36 unknown UIKitApplication:com.xxx[0x57b4][258]

```
<Notice>: Ran out of trampolines of type 0 in
    '/private/var/mobile/Applications/6104C1ED-5D11-4871-B011-91C23C8D6C83/
```

In the past I got the same error but for type 1 and type 2. I was able to fix that problem with the following argument in the compiler.

```
-aot "nrgctx-trampolines=4048" -aot "nimt-trampolines=4048"
```

I wanted to know what is the equivalent for the type 0 reported above or how to address error

Comment: Your question lacks the detail needed to answer, can you provide more context?

Comment: I'm writing an app for the Iphone using Monotouch. When I deploy the application on my iphone I get the error at runtime
Thu Mar 10 23:38:36 unknown UIKitApplication:com.xxx[0x57b4][258] <Notice>: Ran out of trampolines of type 0 in '/private/var/mobile/Applications/6104C1ED-5D11-4871-B011-91C23C8D6C83/

In the past I got the same error but for type 1 and type 2. I was able to fix that problem with the following argument in the compiler. -aot "nrgctx-trampolines=4048" -aot "nimt-trampolines=4048" . I wanted to know what is the equivalent for the type 0 reported above or how to address error

Comment: Please link to the documentation describing your other fixes.

Comment: Please file a bug at http://monotouch.net/Support and attach a sample solution which exhibits this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Type 0 are method trampolines.  The parameter you want is

```
-aot "ntrampolines=4048"
```

From the mono man pages:

ntrampolines=[number]
When  compiling  in full aot mode, the method trampolines
must be  precreated  in  the  AOT  image.   You  can  add
additional   method   trampolines   with  this  argument.
Defaults to 1024.

Answer (score 1):

Alchemy already provided a good answer (upvote for that), I just want to sum up the different types and their default values.

**Mono trampolines:**

- type 0 (generic methods?): `-aot "ntrampolines=xxxx"` (default: 1024)
- type 1 (recursive generics): `-aot "nrgctx-trampolines=xxxx"` (default: 1024)
- type 2 (interfaces): `-aot "nimt-trampolines=xxxx"` (default: 128)

source: http://www.kurokatta.org/grumble/2012/02/out-of-trampolines