# Error Message "Ran out of trampolines type 0"

Tags: xamarin.ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ran out of trampolines of type 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278592/ran-out-of-trampolines-of-type-0)

We are testing our App based on MonoTouch for iOS 5.2.12

Randomly I have this error message:

Ran out of trampolines of type 0 in '/private/var/mobile/Applications/44063255-89FC-437A-B956-E54BF14D103D/MobileCrmMT28.app/mscorlib.dll' (1024)

Does anybody could help me, suggesting a solution/workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try looking here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278592/ran-out-of-trampolines-of-type-0  they seem to suggest some solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the number of trampolines by setting the build flags, in the "extra mtouch arguments" in the iPhone Build setting.

For more information, see this:

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting#Ran_out_of_trampolines_of_type_0